# MySQL: "Sending data" vs "Copying to tmp table"

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have 2 queries that do the same thing and give the same result set, but writing differently. Looking at their profile, they take almost the same time to execute: around 0.075 seconds

The fascinating thing is that query#1 takes almost all of  the entire process execution time in the state "Copying to tmp table". As query#2 takes almost the entire process execution time in the state "Sending data".

So, my question is:

What state is better for a MySQL query to spent all of its time, "Sending data" or "Copying to tmp table"?

query#1 (spends execution time in the state "Copying to tmp table")

```
SELECT ac.album_category_id, ac.name, ac2.album_category_id, ac2.name, ac2.description, t2.total
FROM album_category ac
JOIN album_category ac2 ON ac2.parent_album_category_id = ac.album_category_id
JOIN (
    SELECT a.album_category_id cat_id, SUM(result.count_image) total
    FROM album a
    JOIN (
        SELECT IFNULL(a.parent_album_id, a.album_id) p_album_id, COUNT(ai.image_id) count_image
        FROM album_image ai
        JOIN album a ON a.album_id = ai.album_id
        JOIN image i ON i.image_id = ai.image_id
        WHERE i.is_listed = 1
        GROUP BY p_album_id
    ) result ON result.p_album_id = a.album_id
    GROUP BY a.album_category_id
) t2 ON t2.cat_id = ac2.album_category_id
ORDER BY ac.position, ac2.position
```

query#2 (spends execution time in the state "Sending data")

```
SELECT ac.album_category_id, ac.name, ac2.album_category_id, ac2.name, ac2.description, t3.total
FROM album_category ac
JOIN album_category ac2 ON ac2.parent_album_category_id = ac.album_category_id
JOIN (
    SELECT a2.album_category_id cat_id, SUM(t2.sum_image) total
    FROM album a2
    JOIN (
        SELECT IFNULL(a.parent_album_id, a.album_id) p_album_id, SUM(t1.count_image) sum_image
        FROM album a
        JOIN (
            SELECT ai.album_id album_id, COUNT(ai.image_id) count_image
            FROM album_image ai
            JOIN image i ON i.image_id = ai.image_id
            WHERE i.is_listed = 1
            GROUP BY ai.album_id
        ) t1 ON t1.album_id = a.album_id
        GROUP BY p_album_id
    ) t2 ON t2.p_album_id = a2.album_id
    GROUP BY a2.album_category_id
) t3 ON t3.cat_id = ac2.album_category_id
ORDER BY ac.position, ac2.position
```

**EDIT**

As per jkavalik request, i've added the EXPLAIN. I'm not sure how to add it in text, so i've added images instead. Hope that's ok.

EXPLAIN for query #1

[image]

EXPLAIN for query #2
[image]

Comment: To find out you need to check the query execution plan using [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html). Please add plans for these two queries to the question.

Comment: ok, i've edited the question and added the EXPLAIN

Answer (score 0):

**Copying to tmp table**: The server is copying to a temporary table in memory.

**Sending data**: The thread is reading and processing rows for a SELECT statement, and sending data to the client. Because operations occurring during this state tend to perform large amounts of disk access (reads), it is often the longest-running state over the lifetime of a given query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/general-thread-states.html

Sending data will happen on most queries but the query state will change so fast on quick queries that you won't even notice it. However, since you are noticing it, there may be a lot of IO going on at that time. When you run that query, in a terminal window also look at `iostat -x 10` and watch the disk IO wait (assuming you are using Linux/Unix). If the wait shoots up, the MySQL is reading from disk, doing its work and then preparing to push the data to client.

Copying to tmp table means that the result of a part of query or subquery is moved to memory so that more work can be done using that temporary data (temp table). Whenever I have encountered this state, there's a possibility of optimization. I'd be more concerned about both states if query is taking several seconds to return. I'd optimize query 1 in your case. You might want to try increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size (assuming you are using innodb engine)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html